# Lower continuously my media volume with a button

Tags: java, android, events, button, listener

I want to lower (or upper) my media volume in my application when an "OnLongClickEvent" is detected.

Here my sources :

```
buttongauche.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                playSound(R.raw.volumevoixdiminue);
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Actually, it's work : when I do a longClick on my "buttongauche", the volume is decreased by 1.
Now I would like to know how could I do if I want to lower the sound continuously (for example, decrease sound by 1 every 2 seconde when the button is down).

My button "buttongauche" has already an "onClickEvent", who do other things (change the index of a menu).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare field `boolean touching = false;` that says whether or not you are touching the button and use `OnTouchListener` to change it. When you start touching also start `volumeThread` that lowers the volume every 1 second, and dies when you stop touching.

```
buttongauche.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {       

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {            
        switch (event.getAction()) {                               
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                              
            touching = true;                                       
            Thread volumeThread = new Thread() {                   
                public void run() {                                    
                    while (touching) {                             
                        audio.adjustStreamVolume(                  
                                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,         
                                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,         
                                AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);     
                        try {                                      
                            sleep(1000);                           
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {         
                            e.printStackTrace();                   
                        }                                          
                    }                                              
                }                                                  
            };                                                     
            volumeThread.start();                                  
            break;                                                 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                                
            touching = false;                                      
            break;                                                 
        }                                                          
        return false;                                              
    }                                                              
});
```